# What is the advantage of using tuple over dictionary as a return type?

Tags: swift

Beside tuple is shorter and easy to write what are the other advantages of using a tuple over a dictionary as a function's return data type.

```
let httpResponse0 = (404, "not found")

let httpResponse1 = ["code": 404, "status": "not found"]
```

Comment: A tuple is a group of zero or more values represented as one value. Tuple can have values of different type (unlike dictionary). Tuple can have value without key (unlike dictionary)

Comment: @NiravD doesn't 'Any' becomes its type?

Comment: @sasquatch Yes Any is its type but with that you can store any value.

Comment: @NiravD if you use Any you lose type-safety, where a tuple maintains type-safety.

Comment: @Nirav D Isn't it different to the compiler?

Comment: You can store anything as a string. That doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Comment: I propose a third approach: Use an enum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Collecting some and adding a couple more:

1. A tuple is type-safe way of containing multiple value with multiple types
2. Compared to a dictionary, it's much lighter weight, particularly since the keys are entirely compile time.
3. Keys are optional
4. Keys, if used are compiler maintained and unlikely to get spelled wrong.

Disadvantages:

1. It's easy to get lazy and not name elements which can lead to confusion and unreadable code.
2. It's not Obj-c compatible

Personally I'd prefer to use a light weight object or struct instead of either in most cases.  It's more explicit while still light weight.